# How to fire or execute http service when link is clicked in angular route in single page web app?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

Requirement : I want to click on a menu item which is in single page app and by clicking on that link, loads a view employee.html via $routeProvider and the view should load my employee details by the help of angular service.

In short - executing an angular service on view load by angular route

**I do not know the angular code from beginning to end**

Following is the Code:

/*Spring MVC controller which returns a list in JSON format*/

```
 @ResponseBody 
    @RequestMapping(value="/details", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Employee> details() throws Exception {
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeService.getEmployees();
        return employeeList;
    }
```

/* JSON which is returned is : */

```
[{"employeeId":111,"fName":"John"},
{"employeeId":112,"fName":"Peter"},
{"employeeId":113,"fName":"Brad"}]
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
      <body ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="employeeCtrl">
<!-- http://localhost:8080/web/details/ is the Spring Java URL from which I get the JSON -->
                <a href="http://localhost:8080/web/details/">Get All Employees</a>
                <a href="#">Link2</a>

                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

```
/* AngularJS */
     var app = angular.module(["myApp"]);
                app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider      
                            .when("??", { /* dont know the URL to be entered here */
                                templateUrl: "views/employees.html"
                            })      
                            });
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

You got it backwards. The link in your template should not point to the backend URL from which you get the JSON. It should point to the URL of the route displaying the employees. For example:

```
<a href="#/employees">Get All Employees</a>
```

and

```
$routeProvider.when("/employees", {
                      templateUrl: "views/employees.html",
                      controller: "EmployeesController"
                    })
```

Then, in the EmployeesController, use the $http service to get the employees as JSON from the backend:

```
$http.get('/web/details').then(function(response) {
  $scope.employees = response.data;
});
```

I would change the mapping from /details to /employees, too, since that's what you get from that URL.

Comment: Brilliance. Works like a charm. Thankyou so much geek!